# jQuery selector by two possible values

Tags: jquery

I am trying to filter elements where `data-value` is either `1` or `2`. How can I do it? I am trying:

```
$('body').find('[data-value="1|2"]');
```

And I'm pretty sure the pipe character was also used in jQuery to select between different values but apparently not.

I can use `filter()` but I am looking for a more compact way like shown above, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a comma

```
$('body').find('[data-value="1"], [data-value="2"]');
```